# Using variables in salience declaration in a rule definition

Tags: clips

I want to use a variable bound in the LHS to declare the salience of a rule in order to prioritize rules with a stricter time limit defined in the fact database. I figured the following should work:

```
(set-salience-evaluation when-activated)
(deffunction testsal (?a ?b) (integer (+ ?a ?b)))
(defrule testr
  (declare (salience (testsal ?a 4)))
  (sal ?a)
  ?tf <- (fire testr)
  =>
  (printout t "Running testr")
  (retract ?tf)
)
(assert (sal 3))
(assert (fire testr))
```

But this fails with an error:

```
[EVALUATN1] Variable a is unbound
[PRCCODE6] This error occurred while evaluating arguments for the deffunction testsal.

[PRNTUTIL8] This error occurred while evaluating the salience for defrule testr.

ERROR:
(defrule MAIN::testr
   (declare (salience (testsal ?a 4)
```

Is there a way to use a variable that is bound in the LHS in the salience declaration of the rule?

If not, what is the common way to prioritize depending on some facts in the fact base? Note that I do not want to disallow the rule to fire, I just want to prioritize other rules, so simply adding a constraint to the LHS would probably not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable rather than a fact:

```
CLIPS> (set-salience-evaluation when-activated)
when-activated
CLIPS> (defglobal ?*sal-a* = 0)
CLIPS> 
(defrule testr
  (declare (salience (+ ?*sal-a* 4)))
  ?tf <- (fire testr)
  =>
  (printout t "Running testr")
  (retract ?tf))
CLIPS> (bind ?*sal-a* 3)
3
CLIPS> (assert (fire testr))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (agenda)
7      testr: f-1
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS>
```

Comment: But then I can't make the salience depend on the grounding of the rule, can I? My goal is to have a rule that can be activated with two different groundings, and I want to prioritize one over the other.

Comment: You can bind the value of the global in a pattern: (sal ?a&:(bind ?*sal-a* ?a)). However, in order for this to work properly, each rule must have its own global variable.